# Which is the best Framework to design Java ME application?

Tags: java, user-interface, mobile, java-me

I heard about Java Me UI design is very complex using Java ME SDK.Is there any Framework available to develop UI design easier?
Can any one tell the framework?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use this one.. It's quite easy to use and have GUI Builder

[LWUIT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

try this, one , [www.j2mepolish.org](http://www.j2mepolish.org)

you can find various gui designing in it. It is very simple. code is based on the CSS style like in website designing.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, I feel [LWUIT](http://www.lwuit.com/) is good to use and good to develop the application. Also its easy to learn. So I suggest LWUIT is best one. Its supports [Java ME, Blackberry and Android.](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html)

- [LWUIT blog](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html)

Answer (score 3):

I also use http://www.lwuit.com/. The Lightweight User Interface Toolkit (LWUIT) is a versatile and compact API for creating attractive application user interfaces for mobile devices. LWUIT provides sophisticated Swing-like capabilities without the tremendous power and complexity of Swing. Designed from the ground up as an efficient mobile user interface toolkit, LWUIT provides many useful Swing-like features.

LWUIT offers a basic set of components, flexible layouts, style and theming, animated screen transitions, and a simple and useful event-handling mechanism. The toolkit has been tested and debugged on a variety of mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

1. Perhaps this can help : [GUI Design in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272801/gui-design-in-j2me)
2. Check this as well : http://code.google.com/p/kuix/

Answer (score 2):

I go with @bharath, @frayab and @Bryan Giovanny - LWUIT is the bomb!
I use LWUIT extensively - and the developers have promised us the ability to even develop for iPhone this year!
Check out the LWUIT blog link bharath posted.